# Styling buttons in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm currently working on a project with p5.js and have come against a problem in javascript. I built buttons in javascript to help make certain functions work and I'm looking for a way to style the buttons. For the rest of the project I was using bootstrap so I'm trying to find a way to style it as similar as I can to the rest of the rest off the CSS if possible. The buttons code in javascript follows this.

```
button1 = createButton('start');
button2 = createButton('stop');
button3 = createButton('play');
button4 = createButton('save');

button1.mousePressed(start_);
button2.mousePressed(stop_);
button3.mousePressed(play_);
button4.mousePressed(save_);
```

Comment: You can style DOM elements in p5 with css as you would with anything else. You could create a div with the `id="buttons"`, style it in css, and use the function `button1.parent("buttons")` to add them to the div. more info here: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/parent

Comment: Thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 1):

`createButton` returns a [`p5.Element`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element) object which has a [`.class()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/class) method to set the class property on it. Classes can then be used for styling, either with bootstrap or custom CSS. For example:

```js
let btn;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  const cls = "maroon-bg white-text";
  btn = createButton("hello world");
  btn.class(cls);
  btn.mouseClicked(() => {
    btn.class(btn.class() ? "" : cls);
  });
}
```

```css
.maroon-bg {
  background-color: maroon;
}

.white-text {
  color: white;
}

button {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I prefer separating CSS and JS because it promotes reuse and keeps your JS clean, but if you want to inline your styles, you can use [`.style()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/style):

```js
let btn;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  btn = createButton("hello world");
  btn.style("background-color", "maroon");
  btn.style("color", "white");
  btn.style("padding", "1em");
  btn.mouseClicked(() => {
    if (btn.style("color") === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
      btn.style("color", "white");
      btn.style("background-color", "maroon");
    }
    else {
      btn.style("background-color", "");
      btn.style("color", "");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

This is clearly awkward for this use case, but it can come in handy in other situations and is shown for completeness.